# Tension of a string (massless or with a certain mass) in a simple Newton's laws problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Here is an example of a simple problem which involves the third Newton's law.

There are two cars: a small one and a big one. Being connected by a rope they are driving at their maximal powers in opposite directions. Naturally, the big car is more powerful and the whole system (2 cars and the rope) moves towards the direction of the big car's motion. Friction is present. 
It is said that two cars are pulling the rope equally.

I am quite confused now with this fact of 'equal pulling'. If the rope is massless then the pulling forces MUST be equal, but this is an approximation. If, let's say, the mass of the rope is small but not zero, will the pulling forces still be the same? I mean, after all, the rope as a part of the whole system is moving, so there must be some resulting force acting on it.

Also, the whole idea of tension works to me only if the forces on the opposite sides of the rope are equal. Then the tension is equal to the magnitude of this force everywhere. If the forces on the opposite sides are unbalanced, what is the tension then?

Answer (score 2):

> If, let's say, the mass of the rope is small but not zero, will the pulling forces still be the same?

No.  If the system is accelerating to the right, then the tension on the right hand side of the rope will be larger than the tension on the left, by an amount equal to the mass of the rope times its acceleration.

> If the forces on the opposite sides are unbalanced, what is the tension then?

If the forces are unbalanced, then the tension will simply be non-uniform.  It will be a function of the position along the rope.

As an operational definition, $T(x)$ is force between any two pieces of rope which meet at the point $x$.  In other words, if piece $A$ occupies the interval $(a,x)$ and piece $B$ occupies the interval $(x,b)$, then $A$ feels a force $T(x)$ to the right due to $B$, and $B$ feels a force $T(x)$ to the left from $A$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be correct then to say that the equal tensions in the case of a massless rope is purely a toy model, or maybe even a physically wrong statement? Or is it still a good approximation for a rope with a very low mass? Would it be possible to give a reference where this non-uniform tension is defined?

Comment: @CHILLQQ It's a useful approximation, which might be good or bad depending on the circumstances (which is true of basically everything in physics).  If the mass of the rope is much smaller than the masses at either end, then it's a pretty good approximation.

Comment: It just seems so strange to me that if the rope is massless then two cars are pulling equally, and if the rope is not massless then they are pulling with different forces. Is that really the way it works? Or maybe I am still missing something?

Comment: @CHILLQQ The difference between the tensions at the ends of the rope is proportional to the rope's mass.  As the rope gets less and less massive, the tensions get closer together, and in the limit as the mass of the rope goes to zero, the tensions become equal.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much once more! If you will think of something to read about this can I please ask you to give me a link?

Comment: @CHILLQQ Imagine attaching a length of dental floss to a 1 kg mass and lifting it off the floor.  If the mass is stationary, the force exerted by the bottom of the floss on the 1 kg mass is 1 N, and the downward force on your hand is very nearly also 1 N.  If you repeat the experiment with a 2 kg chain, the chain will *also* exert 1 N of force on the mass (otherwise it would be accelerating upward), but now the downward force on your hand is 3 N.  Does this seem strange to you?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused. You take the cain/floss and attach a weight to it while holding it horizontally with your hands (holding both ends) ?

Comment: @CHILLQQ Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107332/discussion-between-j-murray-and-chillqq).